# Continue discussions raised at Area51?

Tags: discussion

There are some discussions at Area51 that may not be resolved yet.

One of the most intriguing is [Done! Now restore this site to ESL (“English as a Second Language”)](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8808/done-now-restore-this-site-to-esl-english-as-a-second-language), but there may be more.

I'm wondering if they can be moved here so that we did not check for news at two places.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While it's *possible* to relocate such discussions, generally there's no good reason to. The suggestion to rename got something between "NO!" and "MEH!", so it entered private beta under the ELL moniker. Unless there's a *very good* reason to change it, it won't change.

So, if you think there's a good reason to change the name *now*, you should probably just start a new discussion here, stating your rationale, and let the folks using the site chime in.